# Convert a fraction to a mixed number - Java Method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have the following method in a program of mine to return a mixed number form of a fraction:

```
//Method to return mixed number form of fraction
public String toMixed(){
    String mixedNum;
    int wholeNum;
    wholeNum = Math.floorDiv(numerator,denominator);

    if (wholeNum == 0){
        mixedNum = numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }
    else if (numerator % denominator == 0)
        mixedNum = wholeNum + "";
    else if (wholeNum < 0)
        mixedNum = wholeNum + " " +
            -1*(numerator - wholeNum*denominator) + "/" + denominator*-1;
    else
       mixedNum = wholeNum + " " +
            (numerator - wholeNum*denominator) + "/" + denominator;

    return mixedNum;
```

While this works for positive numbers, I am getting incorrect returns for negative numbers. What I am wondering, is there another, better way to create a mixed number form of a fraction in Java, or would it be easier to manipulate this to work for negative numbers by first converting the number sent to the method to a positive if negative, then converting it to a mixed number, then back to a negative? Anyway I thank you for your time and help, I hope this was easy enough to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the GCD of n and d is 1 and d is not negative, here is how you would do it:

```
public static String toiMixed(int n, int d){
        if(n>=0) return n/d +"  "+ n%d + "/"+d;
        String s = n/d-1 + "  ";
        while((double)n/(double)d<0) n+=d;
        return s + n%d + "/" + d;
}
```

Feel free to ask if you need more help.